# mysql get field value before delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a problem!
I have an attachment table. I store file name in this table. My category table and attachment have relation together, if a category delete, related records on attachment removed too but I want to get file name from attachment before delete it!

What should I do ?

```
DELETE c, a category c 
  JOIN attachment a ON c.id = a.extId 
 WHERE c.lft BETWEEN @left AND @right
```

I want to get file name value ( an attachment field ) before delete it in top query

Answer (score 3):

Create a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_attachment_each AFTER DELETE ON attachment FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO deleted_attachments (id, attachment_id, filename, timestamp) 
    VALUES (null, old.id, old.filename, NOW());
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger will fire `after` every `delete` `for each row` that gets deleted from attachment and will add a row to a table "deleted_attachments".

There are triggers `BEFORE` and `AFTER` any action.
The action can be `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`.
The values before the change can be accessed by using the `old` virtual table. The values after the change can be accessed by using the `new` virtual table.
Here I used the `old` values, because `delete` obviously does not have `new` values.

For more about triggers see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html

Or search stackoverflow for `mysql triggers`.

Answer (score 2):

Execute two queries, the first one a `select` with the same `join` and `where` and the second your `delete` query:

```
SELECT attachment.filename 
FROM attachment AS a 
JOIN category AS c ON c.id = a.extId 
WHERE c.lft BETWEEN @left AND @right
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete queries do not return values, so I suggest you perform a simple select statement beforehand to get the filename.  Then proceed with the delete statement.